# toggle visibility for click and load events

Tags: jquery

I have a form that should show toggle visibility of some input boxes depending on the value of a radio button. I want to perform this action during on click and also during on load. I came up with defining a function that is called twice on both events.

I tried using `on.('click load', function()...)` but this didn't work.

Is there a prettier way of doing the below?

```
$(function() {
  toggleQuestions($('.subscribe-how input'));       
  function toggleQuestions(e){
    $('.custom-questions').hide();      
    $('.custom-question-'+$(e).val()).show();       
  };
  $('.subscribe-how input').on('click', function(e){
    toggleQuestions(this);
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this:

```
  function toggleQuestions(e){
    $('.custom-questions').hide();      
    $('.custom-question-'+e).show();        
  }
  $(function() {
    $('.subscribe-how :input').on('click', function(e){
      toggleQuestions(this.value);
    }).click(); 
  });
```

Put the function outside and pass the value directly from the click event callback function.